# Why am I getting Undefined variable or index on my localhost by not my live server?

Tags: php, wamp

Set up WAMP and am getting Undefined variable or index but my live file works fine. Trying to figure out the differences in my software so that I can make sure files work the same when they go live. Is there a setting? I verified and it appears that I am running the same versions of PHP, MySQL, & Apache.

Changed from

```
$validateBus=$_GET["validateBus"] ?? '';         
$validateBus=$_GET["validateBus"];
```

I can fix those errors, but then more code breaks because of the changes. I just do not want to have to ftp every time I make a change.

Comment: Can you show the exact error as it appears? It's possible that you have errors display on on your local but not on you server (which is fine)

Comment: if you are trying the short-hand of the if statement, try the following: `$validateBus= $_GET["validateBus"] ? $_GET["validateBus"] : '';`

Comment: @coderodour The first one should be `isset($_GET["validateBus"])`. Otherwise you'll get the same warning about undefined index.

Comment: What did you change to?

Comment: The issue was errors displaying on my working files and not displayed on my live ones. Thanks @Ibu for that.

Comment: **That means you still have errors in your code, but you are ignoring them** I would suggets fixing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accessing `$_GET["validateBus"]` while the index is not defined. You have to check if it is set first using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
$validateBus = isset($_GET["validateBus"])? $_GET["validateBus"] : '';
```